# NIntegrate: the order of singular points matters!

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, singularity

Consider the following integral:
$$I = \int_{-5}^5 \frac{1}{(x(x-2))^{1/3}} dx.$$
The exact value is `6.30249 - 2.2405 I`. I will perform `NIntegrate` in 3 different ways:

1. Naive method:

   `NIntegrate[1/((x (x - 2)))^(1/3), {x, -5, 5}]`

> 6.28841 - 2.23957 I

Warning occurs.

2. Singularity handling with correct order

   `NIntegrate[1/((x (x - 2)))^(1/3), {x, -5, 0, 2, 5}]`

> 6.30249 - 2.2405 I

No warning occurs, and the result is the most accurate.

3. Singularity handling with wrong order

   `NIntegrate[1/((x (x - 2)))^(1/3), {x, -5, 2, 0, 5}]`

> 6.29582 - 2.2454 I

Warning occurs.

From this observation, we observe that the order of singularity points matters. Is this phenomenon general, so that the intermediate singular points $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ should be given with $x_1<\cdots <x_n$?

Another question is about a double integral. Suppose that an integrand has a singularity at $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x=y$. In this case, we cannot give the singular point information in the right order! For example, assuming the integration range to be $[-10,10]\times [10,10]$,

```
{x, -10,0,10}, {y,-10, 0, x, 10}
```

does not work since it is not necessarily true that $0<x$. In this case, what should I do? (Divide the region? Then how about integration on $\mathbb R^n$, where the integrand is singular on $x_i=0$ and $x_i=x_j$?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that

```
{x, x1, x2, x3,..., xn}
```

describes a path in the real or complex domain, and the order matters. So

```
{x, -5, 2, 0, 5}]
```

integrates from `x == -5` to `x == 2` (passing a singularity), from `x == 2` back to `x == 0`, and then from `x == 0` to `x == 5` (passing another singularity).

For

```
{x, -10, 0, 10}, {y, -10, 0, x, 10}
```

I use

```
{x, -10, 0, 10}, {y, -10, Min[0, x], Max[0, x], 10}
```

`NIntegrate` does fine when `x == 0` and `Min[0, x] == Max[0, x] == 0`.
You can also use `Exclusions -> {x == 0, y == 0, y == x}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think your suggestion is how I should proceed my problem.

Answer (score 11):

> we observe that the order of singularity points matters.

To avoid this, use the `Exclusions` option instead of listing them in order. Now the order does not matter any more since it is a list and not a sequence. From help on `Exclusions`

> Specify the location of the singularity to handle it with appropriate
> transformations:

```
NIntegrate[1/((x (x - 2)))^(1/3), {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> {2, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
NIntegrate[1/((x (x - 2)))^(1/3), {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> {0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both give same result and no warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a further question: does this method also work for `LocalAdaptive` method? As far as I know, if one gives `Exclusions` option in `LocalAdaptive` method, the Mathematica automatically changes to `GlobalAdaptive` method. (By the way, it seems that my integrand can be computed efficiently for `LocalAdaptive` method.)

Comment: @eigenvalue I really do not know as I have not used these methods. But may be this could be made a separate question. It is up to you.